# How can I speed up betadisper function in R on gene expression data using vegan package?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to run betadisper with some gene expression data and the code is taking a very long time to run. I could leave it overnight and in the morning it will still be running. I just recently updated my R program and I am not sure what could be causing this lag.

My code is as follows:

```
library(vegan)
d2 <- assay(vsdUPBVc3) #vsdUPBVc3 is variance transformed data from DESeq2
dist_mat2 <- vegdist(d2)
groups <- factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3), rep(5,3), rep(6,3), rep(7,3), rep(8,3)), labels = c("18PBVc","Lcon", "Vc", "12PBVc", "2PBVc", "12PB", "18PB", "2PB"))
PB.betadisper <- betadisper(d = dist_mat2, group = groups, type = "centroid")
```

Everything above the last line runs without issue, but as soon as it gets to betadisper, no progress is made.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Your example defines data with 24 observations. In my laptop betadisper with that size of problem takes less than 1 msec. We need a reproducible example.